# perform table with simple statistics in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select
x1.
x2
...
x100
from mytab
```

how do i calculate the mean, minimum, maximum, standard deviation for all 100 columns

I.E in output

```
column  mean    min max sigma
x1      1          1    1   1
x2      1          1    1   1
x3      1          1    1   1
```

How to do it?

Comment: Looks like a horrible table design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would unpivot and then do aggregation:

```
select v.colname, avg(v.val), min(v.val), max(v.val), stdev(v.val)
from t cross apply
     (values ('x1', x1), ('x2', x2), . . .
     ) v(colname, val)
group by v.colname;
```

You need to list all the columns in the `values()` clause.  You might find this easier to construct using a SQL query or spreadsheet.

Comment: ('x1', x1), ('x2', x2), . i am too want unpivot,  but,  how to do for all 100cols  without manually?

Comment: As I say in the answer, you can use a SQL query on the metadata tables or using a spreadsheet to construct the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

--If you wish to unpivot without manually hand-coding for 100 columns, one option would be to generate the query string by running a query such as

```
select distinct 
       concat('x',number,',') as col1
  from master..spt_values
where number>=1 and number<=100
```

This will generate rows as follows

```
col1
x1,
x10,
x100,
x11,
```

Copy the results and stick it into the unpivot clause

As an example..

```
create table t(x1 int, x2 int, x3 int)

insert into t values(1,1,1)
insert into t values(1,1,1)
insert into t values(1,1,1)

select y
      ,max(x) as max_x
      ,min(x) as min_x
      ,avg(x) as avg_x
 from t
unpivot(x for y in (<use_values_from_query_generator>))m
group by y
```